# How to I make a parent div resize height based on children dimensions in this example?

Tags: css

I'm making a section that lists user reviews on a website I'm working on.  The problem I'm having is when someone posts too long of a review, the div won't resize to fit the text, so the text either overflows, or cuts off at the bottom of the div.  I wish I could be more specific with my question, but I have so many nested div's here, I don't know which one I should edit.  http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/MYKeOB

HTML

```
<BR>
<BR>
<BR>

<div class="maincontainer">
<div class="reviewrow">
<div class="commentpanel">
<div class="reviewerpic">
  <img src="mugshot.img"></div>

<div class="authordiv">
<strong>Reviewed by Dave</strong>
<div class="stars"><img src="/static/img/stars.png"> </div>

<hr>
<div class="reviewcomment">This is less a "pros and cons" review than a hopefully useful commentary about the Kindle compared with other eReaders and what it means for the eBook industry. (I believe that everything has changed with the Kindle's creation.)

For many years I have been an avid reader of eBooks using almost every eReading device on the market. So as an early-adopter of techie gadgets I had been anxiously awaiting Amazon's Kindle since its first rumors. So I immediately purchased it both out of curiosity and hoping for a better "next generation" eBook solution. In case you're wondering whether I'm "that" Steve Gibson, I probably am -- I'm the guy who gets Google's first three 
So, for what it's worth, if this posting is discovered by any truly interested pre-purchasers, I hope that the following commentary might place the Kindle in "perspective" and be of some value to you. (And if it is, I hope you'll click the button at the bottom to indicate that, so that this review might be found by more potential buyers ... Thank you!)</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="reviewrow">
<div class="commentpanel">
<div class="reviewerpic">
  <img src="{{ i.author.get_profile.get_mugshot_url }}"></div>

<div class="authordiv">
<strong>Reviewed by Cindy</strong>
<div class="stars"><img src="/static/img/stars.png"> </div>

<hr>
<div class="reviewcomment">Hello.  This is a short review.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.maincontainer {
  position:relative;
}
.reviewrow {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0.9375em;
    margin-right: 0.9375em;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
}

.commentpanel{
  width:955px;
  height:115px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color:#d8d8d8;
  background:#f2f2f2;
  padding:1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
 }

.reviewerpic {
    position: relative;
    width: 90px;

}

.authordiv {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 796px;
    height: 30px;
    bottom:87px;
}

.stars {
    width:90px;
    top: 0px;
    left:260px;
    width: 70px;
    position: absolute;
}

.reviewcomment {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight:100;
}
```

much easier to look here http://codepen.io/donnaloia/pen/MYKeOB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed some of styles to meet it...

```
.commentpanel{
    width:955px;
    /*height:115px;*/
    overflow: auto;/*added*/
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color:#d8d8d8;
    background:#f2f2f2;
    padding:1.25rem;
    margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.authordiv {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    width: 796px;
    /*  height: 30px;*/
    bottom:87px;
    top: 0px; /**added*/
}
```

Check out the [code pen](http://codepen.io/vinrav/pen/raxLqP)

Comment: Yes, I just caught that I had set a fixed height on .authordiv as well as .commentpanel (pointed out above).  I will accept this as the answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You used the fixed height that's why it is behaving like this

Either you need to change the height to auto or min-height: nnpx

```
.commentpanel{
  width:955px;
  min-height:115px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color:#d8d8d8;
  background:#f2f2f2;
  padding:1.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
 }
```

Comment: Great, thanks.  That takes care of one problem, this still did not fix the issue though, you can see on codepen example.